# Carriage return is deleted during xsl transformation

Tags: xslt, ant

I'm transforming XML file with Ant xslt task.
I have CR-LF at the end of each line in original file, and only LF remains in transformed file. So all content is placed in one line.

XSL code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" />
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="model[@name='docInfoDefaultDetails']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
            <xsl:if test="not(action[@name='attachments'])">
                <action name="attachments" type="object"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And Ant task (${UpdateTest_xml} is link to original xml file, ${UpdateTest_xsl} is link to xsl file):

```
<xslt extension=".xml" in="${UpdateTest_xml}" out="${UpdateTest_xml}.bak.xml"
          style="${UpdateTest_xsl}">
</xslt>
```

How to preserve CRs?

Comment: The line break normalization is part of XML, see https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-line-ends, I don't see why that would result in "all content" being "placed in one line", how do you look at the transformation result?

Comment: It looks in one line in windows notepad.

Comment: And Windows Notepad is your target environment for looking at the XML result of an Ant transformation? I guess then you have to wait for https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2018/05/08/extended-eol-in-notepad/ to hit the Windows Update. This is difficult to fix from within XSLT, unless you use XSLT processor specific extensions like with Saxon http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/extensions/output-extras/serialization-parameters.html `saxon:newline`.  Maybe some with Ant knowledge has another suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @MartinHonnen points out, XML parsers are required to normalize line endings to a single NL character, so by the time XSLT sees the content, the CR characters have already gone.

The serialization rules for XSLT permit the processor to output line endings as CRLF rather than as a single NL, but that's not much help to you if your chosen processor doesn't offer this option -- and I don't know of any that does.

(The output parameter `saxon:newline` mentioned by @MartinHonnen only affects the text output method, not the HTML or XML output methods.)

I think the simplest solution is: don't view XML in NotePad. There are plenty of utilities on the Windows platform that display files with NL line endings quite happily, NodePad is about the only one that doesn't.